# In Blazor, execute a method after validating an InputText by DataAnnotation

Tags: validation, blazor, data-annotations, blazor-editform

I need to check if data typed in a inputtext is valid, and if it is, then execute a method.
(Validation by a `DataAnnotation`).

I tried in the `OnFieldChanged` event of `EditForm` but this one executes before validation.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter OnValidSubmit in EditForm can do this.  Here is an example:

**MyModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    [Required, Range(1, 10)]
    public int Fields2 { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

**MyPage.razor**

```
<EditForm Model="@exampleModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText id="field1" @bind-Value="@exampleModel.Field1"></InputText>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

<h5 hidden="@(!isFormValid)">Form submitted successfully!</h5>

@code {
    MyModel exampleModel = new MyModel();
    bool isFormValid = false;

    void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        isFormValid = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

**Invalid submit:**

[image]

**Valid submit:**

[image]

Comment: I don't mean in the submit process of EditForm, but after changing the value of the inputtext, maybe after TAB pressing. This is why I mentioned the OnFieldChanged.

Comment: Sorry about that Antonito.  Did you try @onblur?

Comment: I'm going to check out the OnBlur event, just as you are suggesting. Your help is valuable, Jason.